# How can I write a Collatz sequence with List::Gen?

Tags: perl, collatz

I love the functional-programming paradigm that [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen) brings to Perl. Writing a [Collatz sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) with it should be doable, albeit a little challenging since the length of the list is not known a priori.

I'm missing the final `1` at the end of the sequence with the following code:

```
use List::Gen '*';
iterate{ $_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2 }->from( 23 )->while( '!=1' )->say;
```

which prints:

```
23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2
```

What I essentially need with this approach is a `do-while`. The documentation makes mention of a `while_`, which is a 'look-ahead' version of `while`, but the interpreter cannot find such a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround that tests the element for `defined`-ness to decide when to end the list. It requires modifying the iterator definition to populate an `undef` element immediately after it encounters a `1` in the chain:

```
iterate{ $_ == 1 ? undef : $_%2  ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2 }->from( 23 )->while( 'defined' )->say;
```

which prints

```
23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works (as a start):

```
use List::Gen '*';
iterate{$_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2}->from(23)->until(sub{$_ == 1 ? (($delay = 1), 0) : $delay})->say();
```

Let me see if I can make a function out of that and make `$delay` safe...

This should work, but doesn't because the function passed to `until` is called twice (except for the first value):

```
use List::Gen '*';
sub after { use feature 'state'; $f = shift(); $f = '$_' . $f unless (ref($f)); sub { state $d; $r = $d; $d = eval $f; $r } }
iterate{ $_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2 }->from( 23 )->until(after('==1'))->say;
```

This works for the double function call:

```
use List::Gen '*';
sub after { use feature 'state'; $f = shift(); $f = '$_' . $f unless (ref($f)); sub { state($d1,$d2); $r = $d2; $d2 = $d1; $d1 = eval $f; $r } }
iterate{ $_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2 }->from( 23 )->until(after('==1'))->say;
```

Still trying to understand why the `until` function is called twice after the first call.

It works only for `until` and not `while`.

The code above only works with string arguments; this one works with function references:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use List::Gen '*';

sub after {
        use feature 'state';
        my $f = shift();
        my $c = ref($f) eq 'CODE'
                        ? '&$f()'
                        : '$_' . $f;
        sub {
                state($d1,$d2);
                my $r = $d2;
                $d2 = $d1;
                $d1 = eval($c);
                $f;
                $r
        }
}
iterate{$_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2}->from(23)->until(after('==1'))->say;
iterate{$_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2}->from(23)->until(after(sub{$_ == 1}))->say;
```

Comment: Hmm...  Had a nice function, but found that after the first `while` or `until` call, subsequent `while` or `until` calls are executed twice for the same value: i.e. 23, 70, 70, 35, 35, 106, 106, ..., 4, 4, 2, 2, 1!  See: `iterate{ $_%2 ? 3*$_+1 : $_/2 }->from( 23 )->while(sub{print "_ = $_\n"; $_ != 1})->say;`

Comment: I figured out a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30664416/133939) that feels cleaner which involves appending an `undef` after the first `1` is encountered and testing for `defined`-ness

Comment: If it wasn't for the double call (which still has me perplexed), I could have make this delay function return `N` additional sequences which might have been useful for non-terminating sequences.